# Anchore Engine: Trying to "add image"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've recently installed the open source version of Anchore Engine to a Ubuntu 20.04 instance, and according to their documentation you can add images via "anchore-cli image add docker.io/library/".  However, I haven't found a way to pull anything but operating system images with this command.  I was hoping to add the following image https://hub.docker.com/r/fsouza/fake-gcs-server to scan, but whenever I attempt to use the "docker.io/library/" option it can't find the name.

I'm sure my formatting is bad, but I don't know if its even possible to use this avenue to pull this image.  I'm looking for some direction on how I would do so.

I've attempted the following commands:

docker-compose exec api anchore-cli image add docker.io/library/r/fsouza/fake-gcs-server

docker-compose exec api anchore-cli image add https://hub.docker.com/r/fsouza/fake-gcs-server

Each has resulted in the following error:
Error: cannot fetch image digest/manifest from registry
HTTP Code: 400

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, and the correct way (if there is a way) to add this image?

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because you entered the wrong link `docker.io/library/r/fsouza/fake-gcs-server`. You can run this command to add your image to the Anchore engine:
`docker-compose exec api anchore-cli image add docker.io/fsouza/fake-gcs-server`